# How to select nodes from xml file when it`s full of ampersands?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net

I have full xml document with ampersands and having problems loading it. I tried replacing all ampersands, but I get error about < symbol. Here is my conversion code:

```
        Dim xmlfile As String

        Dim str As StreamReader = New StreamReader("doc.xml")

        xmlfile = str.ReadToEnd()

         xmlfile = xmlfile.Replace("&amp;", "&")
         xmlfile = xmlfile.Replace("&quot;", Chr(34))
         xmlfile = xmlfile.Replace("&apos;", "'")
         xmlfile = xmlfile.Replace("&lt;", "<")
         xmlfile = xmlfile.Replace("&gt;", ">")

        Dim xmldoc As New XmlDocument
        xmldoc.LoadXml(xmlfile)
```

From here I am getting error...

If I try to load xml file straight without ampersands conversion, It doesn`t select node even if i know it position

```
Dim names as XmlNodeList = xmldoc.selectnodes("/Team/Name[@ID=Grizzlie]/Member")
For each name in names
msgbox(name.OuterXml)
```

But I see no message after running app...

Any ideas why it`s doesn`t show anything or how to read xml document full of ampersants correctly?

Here is sample code from xml:

```
<Team>
<Name ID="Grizzlie"&gt; &lt;Member FirstName=&quot;Thomas&quot; SecondName=&quot;Andreson&quot; /&gt;&lt;Member FirstName=&quot;Nick&quot; SecondName=&quot;Patterson&quot; /&gt;&lt;Member FirstName=&quot;James&quot; SecondName=&quot;Cooker&quot;/&gt;&lt;/Name&gt;
</Team>
```

Comment: Those ampersands are needed for it to be valid xml.  Don't do anything resembling this, it won't work.

Comment: You had a problem. Then you used String.Replace on an Xml file. Now you have many problems.

Comment: What makes you think that your xpath query is correct and you try to make string replacements... See [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: Post (a piece of) the original XML and specify what query you want to run. Also, is XmlDocument+XParh required or would XDocument be OK?

Comment: I have added piece of source. Problem is that doesn`t show me outerxml... even nothing... from what i understand it doesnt` select nodes... query i want to make is Dim names as XmlNodeList = xmldoc.selectnodes("/Team/Name[@ID=Grizzlie]/Member")
For each name in names
msgbox(name.OuterXml)... I am still new to xdocument and started using xmldocument+xpath... Thanks

Comment: @Chelovek It's simple. You *never, never* use String.Replace or any other String method on XML. Repeat after me: Never. XML cannot be processed with string methods and you shall never try.

Comment: @Tomalak `XML cannot be processed with string methods`. I would change it to `should not`. Only hard and error-prone.

Comment: @I4V The answer to the question *"Can I use String methods on XML?"* is *"No!"* until such time as you stop asking because you have understood. There is no *"should not"*.

Comment: I4V what do you advice me?

Comment: @Tomalak I didn't ask anything. And you don't know me. Maybe I am good in xml-specifications, State machines, tokenizing and parsing. Maybe I had written compilers for some less-known languages.  Maybe you are just a jerk.

Comment: @Chelovek Use an xml parser and don't make string operations on it.

Comment: @I4V Oops, the "you" was not meant as "you, personally". It was meant generally, towards the one asking. Maybe you are a little quick to judge and a little snippy in your replies?

Comment: How is the XML file being generated?  It's not valid XML and XmlDocument and XDocument won't parse it.  It looks like it's been partially HTML encoded.  You need to fix the XML file first - any solution you use with the current format of the XML will be a hack and will come back to bite you.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be with your xpath query: the condition @=Grizzlie won't match anything because it is looking for an attribute with an empty name. Perhaps you mean

/Team[@Name='Grizzlie']/Member

Comment: Forgot to add when was writing questions, thanks for reminding.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need quotes round Grizzlie, too? As it stands your XPath query will be searching for a node in which the ID attribute matches the text of child element called 'Grizzlie'.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with your XPath query. I'd verify that it's correct, before assuming something that the document itself is invalid.

Those ampersands are required to make an XML document valid.
They're most likely put in there because the creator, wanted to put these symbols, "<>&'", without it being assumed as real XML.

Edit:
The XML you have is invalid.
http://schneegans.de/sv/